# Javascript radio button group click

Tags: javascript

So I got this bit of code where if I click a radio button I want these other radio buttons to be unclicked if they are cliked and also to be disabled.

So far they get disabled but however they do not get unclicked?

```
if (document.getElementById("None").checked) {
    document.getElementById("HundredsAndThousands").clicked = false;
    document.getElementById("ChocolateSprinkles").clicked = false;
    document.getElementById("SilverBalls").clicked = false;
    document.getElementById("Coconut").clicked = false;

    document.getElementById("HundredsAndThousands").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ChocolateSprinkles").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("SilverBalls").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("Coconut").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: If all your `<input type="radio"/>` shar a `name` attribute, browsers automatically will only allow one. Ex: `<input type='radio' name='myRadios'/><input type='radio' name='myRadios'/>`

Comment: @johnny add radio buttons to your question so you get better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you need to change is called `checked`, not `clicked`:

```
document.getElementById("HundredsAndThousands").checked = false;
document.getElementById("ChocolateSprinkles").checked = false;
document.getElementById("SilverBalls").checked = false;
document.getElementById("Coconut").checked = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done so much better, if you use a jQuery library. You can use `.val()` or `.attr()` to get the value of the radio button.

```
var str = $("#none").attr('checked');
var str = $("input:radio[name=radioname]:checked").val();
```

And `.attr('checked', true);` to change a radio button from checked (to unchecked). To change this on a group

```
$("input:radio[name=mygroup]").attr('checked',true);
```